# Remmina Locked in Full Screen Mode

Tags: window, fullscreen, remmina

From time to time, a [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) remote window will automatically load in full screen mode and cannot be minimized and must be closed to remove it from the screen on the desktop. I have seen this occur on both *Gnome* and *KDE* on fully updated *Ubuntu 20.04 LTE*.

On the remote window, the control bar at the top does show but the only button that works is disconnect (the rightmost button).

What is the best way to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For now the only solution I have found is to close all *remmina* windows and and restart it and this seems to clear up the problem.

I will continue to monitor this as *Remmina* is a daily use tool.

Comment: Same problem here. How do you restart Remmina even after closing all connections? The only way out of it I've found is to reboot the entire client machine (the one running Remmina).

Comment: To close `Remmina`, close any windows and possibly go to system tray icon if enabled, click and select quit. If that does not work, open a task manager and kill from there.

Comment: Thanks. In KDE Plasma (Kubuntu) Ctrl+Esc is the way to get the Task Manager (took me some effort to figure that out). Remmina was stuck in full-screen even after rebooting - I could launch it once, and then had to reboot each time to get out. But killing the window with Task Manger did seem to reset it to work normally.